# read files from directory and display at tree viewer table tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I build table with treeviewer , something like this:

```
PLS     RF      SVR
```

I want to read filed from  specific directory and according to the file name, display it in the correct column. For example if the file name contain "pls" show the file in PLS column and then the user can select one file.

My code so far : ( I don't know how to store the files in the table correctly)

```py
pred_win=tkinter.Toplevel (window) #create new window
pred_win.title ("predict")
pred_win.geometry ("600x600")
treeView = ttk.Treeview (pred_win)
treeView.grid ()
treeView["columns"] = ["PLS", "SVR","RF"]
treeView["show"] = "headings"
treeView.heading ("PLS", text="PLS")
treeView.heading ("SVR", text="SVR")
treeView.heading ("RF", text="RF")
# get the list of files
path = os.getcwd ()
flist = os.listdir (path)
item_list=[x for x in flist ]

for i in range (len(item_list)):
    treeView.insert ('', 'end', values=item_list[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily by using `glob`, you pick the files that have `pls` at the end or the start, or in the middle(and so on..). If the folder list was:

```
coolrf.txt
nicerf.txt
pls.txt
hellopls.txt
sitepls.txt
nicesvr.txt
greatsvr.txt
supersvr.txt
```

Then your code would be:

```py
from glob import glob
from itertools import zip_longest # This is needed to loop through 3 lists at the same time
.... # Same code

pls = glob('*pls.*') # Make a list of all files with pls at the end
svr = glob('*svr.*') # Make a list of all files with svr at the end
rf = glob('*rf.*') # Make a list of all files with rf at the end

item_list = item_list = [tup for tup in zip_longest(pls,svr,rf)] # Make a list of tuples of each file type

for i in item_list:
    treeView.insert ('', 'end', values=i) # Insert each tuple on
```

We are using `zip_longest()` to loop through 3 lists at the same time. We could use `zip()` but if the length of the 3 are not same, then its not going to iterate properly, while `zip_longest()` will. And we are inserting tuples that has field values, into the treeview.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it just insert all to the first column of the table and not divide it according to table headers

Comment: @Moryaa Are you sure your copying the same code out? It worked perfectly fine for me. Could you include a screenshot with the question?